# Entity Form to insert data into Custom Entities

Tags: entities

I am finally getting to Entity Construction Kit. I have built out my entity with fields, I have also set up a feed to import data into the entity.

However, I also need to build a form that will push data into the entity fields in the database. I need to know how to do this. I have search and have yet to find anything that explains or shares knowledge on how to handle this.

Has any built a form that will insert data into the database without a custom coded module?

I do not want to add data from the 'entity list' tab. I actually have a use case where I need to insert several rows of the same thing. So, for instance when doctors show up at an event yet they don't give us there information I still need to insert 5 MD's showed up for the event.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like something Views Bulk Operations or Rules could do, eg you make a "url link" (with Rules Link module) to call an action to add a doctor to an event. You could make more than 1 link, and ever link could have a custom `?number_of_doctors=N` value on it to update the Entity with `N` number of blank doctor entries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can look into that, however, I am still looking for a way to build an EntityForm and get the fields, like First Name etc, into the database fields for the Entity's that I created. I am looking into Form API and Entity API but the process is not straight forward for a site builder.

Comment: I am using ECK and create 3 form but 2 forms is working fine..

3rd form I am calling one menu callback

in 3rd form i have created 3 fields 2 fields 

i am getting value through entity refrence
but  when i submit eck form

 in the database value not inserted

but row is created

Comment: this sounds really weird, and i'm not sure how to help now. sorry.